# Trying to install Drupal modules and themes: keep getting error "does not contain any .info.yml files."

Tags: 8

I am new to Drupal. I am running Drupal 8. I have tried to install three different themes and modules, and keep getting this error:

> does not contain any .info.yml files

Including with the [Beale Street](https://drupal.org/project/bealestreet) module with a 8.x release.

Why am I seeing this error? Are .info.yml files a newish requirement that most themes don't have yet? Where can I get themes that include `.info.yml` files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** you're trying to install a theme or module in Drupal 8, which doesn't contain the required files. You might be trying to install a Drupal 7 (or earlier) module by mistake, or it may not be a Drupal module at all.

The 8.x-dev branch of the Beale Street theme is most definitely not Drupal 8 compatible. It's a straight copy of the current 7.x-dev branch, so it hasn't been converted yet. The maintainer has [said as much](https://drupal.org/node/2073429).

Converting a module/theme from 7.x to 8.x requires a lot more work than just adding a yaml file, and if you don't find one in a particular release you can safely assume it hasn't been converted yet.

There are lists of [modules](https://drupal.org/project/modules/?f[0]=drupal_core%3A7234&f[1]=bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc) and [themes](https://drupal.org/project/themes/?f[0]=drupal_core%3A7234&f[1]=bs_project_sandbox%3A0&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc) on Drupal.org that are tagged with 8.x. As you've seen, not all of them are ready yet. Bear in mind quite a few will still be in -dev, so they're not expected to be useable.